# Create a Dictionary from a list with duplicates

Tags: c#, dictionary

My scenario is that I have a `List<MyObject>` and `MyObject` has a property `ID`. I want to make a dictionary from that list:

```
        var myDic = MyList.ToDictionary(e => e.ID);
```

The problem is that sometimes I have some duplicate ID. In that case I would like to store the first item to the dictionary and ignore the rest, and have some kind of notification of skipped items if possible.

Right now I'm obtaining an Exception telling me that I have duplicate keys in my list but I can't/don't want to modify the original list. Is there a way of performing the task without creating a new list with no duplicate IDs?

Comment: Use `Distinct` to select only distinct items

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var myDic = MyList.ToLookup(x => x.ID)
                  .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First());
```

Answer (score 6):

Just group the items by that property first, then you can pull out the first/last/random/whatever value you want from that group.

```
var dictionary = list.GroupBy(item => item.ID)
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.First());
```